# Цикл для генерирования SQL insert

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql

вот код

```
insert = "insert into [dbo].[0e691f83-19a1-454f-8e18-41dab00cca66_Objects] (IACGUID, 
IACConnector_Guid," \
     " IACObjectClass, IACLastMod, IACPreferredLanguage, IACClientID, 
AlternateEmailAddress, Assistant," \
     " C, CloudLegacyExchangeDN, CloudMSExchArchiveStatus, 
CloudMSExchBlockedSendersHash," \
     " CloudMSExchRecipientDisplayType, CloudMSExchSafeRecipientsHash, 
CloudMSExchSafeSendersHash," \
     " Co, Manager, exportSourceAnchor, AS_AuthenticationAddress)" \
     " values ('3815fa9a-48a3-4be0-9cbe-d1b3844b1cef', '4D032273-BE6A-414B-940D- 
7F6FD53DA771'," \
     " 'user', '12/14/2021', 'xvkrQVJVYG810', 'honiCUVKRY652', 
'tcubbini0@simplemachines.org'," \
     " 'zjuiUIAENT728', 'ghqeDHMUAB051', 'kjhbTUVLBW951', 91, 30, 95, 41, 5, 
'wbpyRFUQHU881', 'yrlvHSMLUV960'," \
     " 'buinEGXOIA598', 'fzdkEJCZKI383');"

  count = 0
  while count < 100:
       print(insert)
       count += 1
```

Сейчас согласно этому запросу печатается 100 инсертов, но с одинаковыми данными. Необходимо чтобы генерило с разными данными. Я пробовал библиотеку random, но там в основном цифры, а надо и строки и цифры и спецсимволы. Подскажите как я могу решить эту задачу??

Comment: Уточните - что именно вы хотите варьировать. В `random` есть `choice`, его можно использовать для случайного выбора из чего угодно, можно из строк.

Comment: Во-первых, в питоне есть многострочные строки - зачем устраивать эту раскоряку с продолжением? Во-вторых, SQL Server поддерживает рекурсивные CTE, так что можно сразу сгенерировать и вставить сотню строк одним запросом.

Comment: а надо и строки и цифры и спецсимволы и GUID

Comment: Не, мне нужен скрипт который буде задействоваться раз в неделю и будет генеритьь данные 100, 1000, 1000000 данных

Comment: Количество генерируемых данных вполне может быть параметром запроса.

Comment: ТАк к чему бы мне прибегнуть лучше всего для генерации SQL данных????????

Comment: Ну используйте форматирование строк, через метод format или f-строки. Для генерации случайного uuid используйте [соответствующий модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html). Случайные строки символов можно через [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) генерировать.